# Strategy to secure server scripts with login credentials

Tags: security, server

have a question regarding security.
We have server with scripts which need to login to various other systems like backup, monitoring  checks etc.
Now what is the best strategy to hide the login credentials ?

Having a cron job for root which is giving credentials as parameter to the script is an option but actually just moves the problem from the user account to root.

Comment: As you are talking about cron jobs the server and the various other systems are Linux systems?

Comment: It is a general question.
It can be Windows Scheduler or Linux Cronjob.